# Android scanning all audio files in removable SD Card

Tags: android

I'm trying to scan all audio files in my SD card. Here is a fragment of code which is responsible for that. But it only returns files from internal storage, not from removable SD card.

```
{..
final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());  
..}

public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for (File singleFile : files) {
        if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
        } else {
            if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3")||singleFile.getName().endsWith(".m4a")||singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")) {
                al.add(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Comment: Have you decided this problem? I have the same

Answer (score -1):

Are you using permission to read external storage?

Also Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns internal storage directory if SDcard is not mounted.

Try using below permission if not using currently:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Yes I have use the permission to read external storage. And SD card is mounted.